# How do I access the following model tables

Tags: django, database

I am working on a Django project and I am a beginner. I have a page which displays the list of incubators (from the database). When I click on them, I want to show the their details for which I have made a separate model class.
models.py:

```
class Incubators(models.Model):      # These are our database files for 

the Incubator Portal
    incubator_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city_location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.FileField()
    verify = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):                  # Displays the following  stuff when a query is made
      return self.incubator_name + '-' + self.owner 

class Details(models.Model):
    incubator = models.ForeignKey(Incubators, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='esc_details')
    inc_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    inc_img = models.FileField()
    inc_details = models.TextField(max_length= 2500)
    inc_address = models.TextField(max_length = 600, default = "Address")
    inc_doc = models.FileField()
    inc_policy = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.inc_name
```

And this is my views for details:

```
def details(request, incubator_id):
    inc = get_object_or_404(Incubators, pk = incubator_id)
    details = Details.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/details.html', {'inc': inc, 'details': details})
```

And this is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/', views.home, name='home'),    # Home page
    url(r'incubators/$', views.incubators, name='incubators'),    # Incubator list page
    url(r'about/', views.about, name='about'),          # Websie about page
    url(r'results', views.result, name = 'result'),         # For search function
    url(r'^incubators/(?P<incubator_id>[0-9]+)', views.details, name = 'details'),      # shows details of incubators
    url(r'incubators/add/$', views.AddIncubator.as_view(), name = 'add-incubator'),     # Adding Inc
]
```

In my template I am able to to display the data from Incubator class in models (eg {{inc.incubator_name}}) but unable to use the Details model.

```
<!-- Title -->


    <h1 class="mt-4">{{ inc.incubator_name }} <p class="lead">
            by
            <a href="#">{{ inc.owner }}</a>
          </p></h1>

          <!-- Author -->

<hr>

          <!-- Preview Image -->
          <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ inc.inc_img.url }}" alt="">

          <hr>

          <!-- Post Content -->
                    <p class="lead">{{ inc.esc_details.inc_details }}</p>


          <blockquote class="blockquote">
            <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
            <footer class="blockquote-footer">Someone famous in
              <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </footer>
          </blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the field that defines the relation between two models is not in the model that you have grabbed an object for, then what you do is use related_name in your model class definition.

```
class Details(models.Model):
    incubator = models.ForeignKey(Incubators, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='banana_pudding')
```

Then in your template you can for example use

```
{{ inc.banana_pudding.inc_address }}
```

Edit: SO, I just noticed that this is a one-to-many relation. I assumed from the context that this was a one-to-one relation. If it is you should use a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) instead of a ForeignKey, and then you can use the template tag I noticed above.

If it really is a one-to-many relationship you get a set of results rather than a single entry which means you will need to itterate over the resulting set. You can do this as follows:

```
{% for banana in inc.banana_pudding.all %}
    {{ banana.inc_address }}
{% endfor %}
```

also you might want to use select_related / [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) if you are going to be doing this. It makes sure all your desired results are grabbed from the database in a single go rather than requiring multiple database hits caused by this template formulation.

Comment: Made changes as you suggested and ran migrations. Still no result

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to access the Detail class elements. Its quite simple.
You just have to add a query in views function.

views.py

```
def details(request, incubator_id):
    inc = get_object_or_404(Incubators, pk = incubator_id)
    details = Details.objects.get(pk = incubator_id)
    return render(request, 'main/details.html', {'inc': inc, 'details': details})
```

Now it can be called using the 'details' variable in HTML file.

Html:

```
<img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ details.inc_img.url }}" alt="">
```